# Which GUI library is used to develop Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: c++, c, firefox, graphics

Which GUI library is used to develop Firefox?

Qt? GTK+? Windows native?

Answer (score 9):

Firefox uses a number of GUI toolkits, including the native Windows one, as well as GTK+ for X platforms. Sadly, [there is no official support for Qt](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Qt).

Comment: "Sadly, it doesn't yet support Qt." The link you provided says exactly the opposite - that Mozilla's QT back-end is available and used in some custom builds of Mozilla. There is no need to use it in binaries distributed because more native back-ends are available and probably considered more suitable (functional/fast/natural).

Comment: @Serge: Thanks, I updated my post to reflect official support. Re "more native back-ends are available": on KDE, Qt _is_ "more native" than GTK+ (or to put it differently, unless you have a GTK+ engine that emulates the look of your current KDE look and feel, your GTK+ apps will look fugly). I'd _love_ to have an officially-supported Qt build to use.

Answer (score 2):

I heard that firefox is using their own GUI based off of XML and its called XUL. At least that's what it sounds like if your read their articles on XUL.